# Delphi 2010 - Could not load SSL lib

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I execute this code and get error: Could not load SSL lib
Class: `EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary`

I do not use .net.

```
var
  Client: TIdHTTP;
  tokenURL: String;
begin
  client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    client.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(client);
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(client.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

    client.HandleRedirects := False; 
    client.Get('https://www.xxxxx.xx/portal/ILlogin?username=XXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXX&skin=yyyyyyyyyy&portal=GG', [300, 301, 302, 303, 305, 306, 307]);

    if client.Response.Location <> '' then
      tokenURL := client.Response.Location;
  finally
    client.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit will tell you why OpenSSL could not be loaded.  Either you do not have the OpenSSL DLLs installed, or you have an incompatible version of the DLLs installed that is missing functionality that Indy is looking for.  Try the DLLs that are available at Indy's [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.Fulgan.com/SSL).

Comment: Also beware of DLL hell. Check your PATH environment variable and then check folders in your path for multiple incompatible versions of the open SSL dlls.

Comment: In the current Indy 10 release, you can avoid that issue by calling the `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to specify the folder that the OpenSSL DLLs are located in.

Comment: Nifty! I didn't know about that call.